# Is it possible to install curl into busybox in kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, busybox

I am using busybox to detect my network problem in kubernetes v1.18 pods. I created the busybox like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
    name: busybox
    namespace: default
spec:
    containers:
    - name: busybox
    image: busybox:1.28
    command:
        - sleep
        - "3600"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    restartPolicy: Always
```

and login to find the kubernetes clusters  network situation:

```
 kubectl exec -it busybox /bin/bash
```

What surprises me is that the busybox does not contain curl. Why does the busybox package not include the curl command? I am searching the internet and find the docs do not talk about how to add curl into busybox. I tried to install curl, but found no way to do this. Is there anyway to add curl package into busybox?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The short answer, is you cannot.

#### Why?

Because busybox does not have package manager like: yum, apk, or apt-get ..

#### Acutally you have two solutions:

**1. Either use a modified busybox**

You can use other busybox images like [progrium/busybox](https://github.com/progrium/busybox) which provides **opkg-install** as a package manager.

```
image: progrium/busybox
```

Then:

```
kubectl exec -it busybox -- opkg-install curl
```

**2. Or if your concern to use a minimal image, you can use alpine**

```
image: alpine:3.12
```

then:

```
kubectl exec -it alpine -- apk --update add curl
```

Answer (score 17):

No.  Consider `alpine` as a base image instead that includes BusyBox plus a package manager, or building (or finding) a custom image that has the tools you need pre-installed.

BusyBox is built as a single binary that contains implementations of many common Linux tools.  The [BusyBox documentation](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html) includes a listing of the included commands.  You cannot "install" more commands into it without writing C code.

BusyBox does contain an implementation of `wget`, which might work for your purposes (`wget -O- http://other-service`).

Answer (score 7):

As others said, the answer is no and you need to use another image.

There is:

- Official curl alpine based image: https://hub.docker.com/r/curlimages/curl with `curlimages/curl`
- Busyboxplus Images: https://hub.docker.com/r/radial/busyboxplus with `radial/busyboxplus:curl`
- [Nixery](https://nixery.dev/) with `nixery.dev/curl`

Image sizes:

```
$ docker images -f "reference=*/*curl"
REPOSITORY           TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
curlimages/curl      latest    ab35d809acc4   9 days ago    11MB
radial/busyboxplus   curl      71fa7369f437   8 years ago   4.23MB
nixery.dev/curl      latest    aa552b5bd167   N/A           56MB
```

Comment: `radial/busyboxplus:curl` is ancient but works to this day

Answer (score 6):

BusyBox has a subset of `wget`. The usage patterns of curl are significantly more complex in your OS than the one that comes with Busybox.

To clarify what I mean, run the following in your OS:

```
$ wget --help | wc -l
207
```

while running wget's help inside Busybox container should give you a minimal subset package:

```
$ docker run --rm busybox wget --help 2>&1 | wc -l
20
```

In K8s, you could run the following:

```
$ kubectl run -i --tty --rm busybox --image=busybox -- sh
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
/ # wget
BusyBox v1.33.1 (2021-06-07 17:33:50 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: wget [-cqS] [--spider] [-O FILE] [-o LOGFILE] [--header 'HEADER: VALUE'] [-Y on/off]
    [--no-check-certificate] [-P DIR] [-U AGENT] [-T SEC] URL...

Retrieve files via HTTP or FTP

    --spider    Only check URL existence: $? is 0 if exists
    --no-check-certificate  Don't validate the server's certificate
    -c      Continue retrieval of aborted transfer
    -q      Quiet
    -P DIR      Save to DIR (default .)
    -S          Show server response
    -T SEC      Network read timeout is SEC seconds
    -O FILE     Save to FILE ('-' for stdout)
    -o LOGFILE  Log messages to FILE
    -U STR      Use STR for User-Agent header
    -Y on/off
```

If `curl` is something required for your use case, I wouldsuggest to use `Alpine` which is `busybox` + a minimal package manager and `libc` implementation such that you can trivially do `apk add --no-cache curl` and get real `curl` (or even `apk add --no-cache wget` to get the "real" wget instead of BusyBox's `wget`).

Answer (score 4):

#### Install the `curl` binary from the source website

Replace `binary-url` with the URL of the binary file found from [curl.se](https://curl.se/download.html)

```bash
export BINARY_URL="<binary-url>"
wget $BINARY_URL -O curl && install curl /bin; rm -f curl
```

Worked with `busybox:latest` image

Answer (score 3):

As @abdennour is suggesting, I'm no longer sticking with `busybox` anymore. Alpine is a very lightweight Linux container image as others suggest here in which you can literally install any UNIX-like tool handy to accomplish your troubleshooting task. In fact, I use this function within my dotfiles at `.bashrc` to spin a handy ephemeral ready-to-rock Alpine pod:

```sh
## This function takes an optional argument to run a pod within a Kubernetes NS, if it's not provided it fallsback to `default` NS.
function kalpinepod () { kubectl run -it --rm --restart=Never --image=alpine handytools -n ${1:-default} -- /bin/ash }

❯ kalpinepod kube-system
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
/ # cat /etc/resolv.conf
search kube-system.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
nameserver 10.245.0.10
options ndots:5
/ # apk --update add curl openssl
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/6) Installing ca-certificates (20191127-r5)
(2/6) Installing brotli-libs (1.0.9-r3)
(3/6) Installing nghttp2-libs (1.42.0-r1)
(4/6) Installing libcurl (7.74.0-r1)
(5/6) Installing curl (7.74.0-r1)
(6/6) Installing openssl (1.1.1j-r0)
Executing busybox-1.32.1-r3.trigger
Executing ca-certificates-20191127-r5.trigger
OK: 9 MiB in 20 packages
```

Answer (score 3):

Or just copy a statically built curl into Busybox:
https://github.com/moparisthebest/static-curl/releases

Answer (score 1):

Radial has an overlay of [busybox images](https://hub.docker.com/r/radial/busyboxplus/) adding cURL. `docker pull radial/busyboxplus:curl`

They also have a second images having cURL + Git. `docker pull radial/busyboxplus:git`